# How can I use different variable names for common Spring Boot Application Properties, when the app never directly calls these variables?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration, configuration-files

I've created a pretty standard **Spring Boot 2.0** app with `Services` and `Repositories` to access a database.

I had to set the standard `Spring Boot application properties` to get it to work, such as:

```
spring.datasource.url, spring.jpa.database, etc.
```

However, in order to **prevent** my properties from **overwriting** other properties in similar apps hosted in the same place, I need to rename these properties, such as:

```
myApp.spring.datasource.url, myApp.spring.jpa.database, etc.
```

Some of these properties will be set by environmental variables instead of the `application.properties` file.

However, I can't see any way to override those variables in my app.

The standard approach is to use @Value to configure those variables. However, the Spring Boot 2.0 setup for services looks up all these properties "behind the scenes," so that doesn't appear to be an option here.

Is there any way to configure my app to read all those `myApp.common.property.name` properties and treat them as `common.property.name`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the standard way is to use `@Value`. But thw work doesn't stop there, you need to create DataSource and EntityManager with these values.

Springboot will create DataSource, Entitymanager and some other components bey looking into default properties(spring.xxx) from the file(hence Spring boot is opinionated). But when you change these names to non default values, then you need to create these components /  beans yourself.

Instead of using `@Value` you could also use `@Configurationproperties`. `@Value` also works but you might need to declare like 6 or 7 values with @Value. If you wish to use @ConfigurationProperties, make sure you have `@EnableConfigurationProperties` annotation added somewhere in your project.

Here is a code snippet. You need to tune it to your project

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
  basePackages = { "com.xxx.yyy.repo" }
)
public class SomeDbConfig {

  @Primary // Use this if you have multiple datasources or else no use
  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myApp.spring.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
  entityManagerFactory(
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
    @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource
  ) {
    return builder
      .dataSource(dataSource)
      .packages("com.xxx.yyy.domain")
      .persistenceUnit("somename")
      .build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory 
    entityManagerFactory
  ) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Jesse Doupvote or accept the answer if it had helped